# symlink doen't works with nginx and php-fpm and docker

Tags: docker, symlink, nginx, wordpress

I run a wordpress site in local wiht docker, and in a plugin I send a GET request for a style.css file, which is a symlink, and it doesn't work, it answer a `404 not found`

I don't think the probleme is in wordpress side, because the GET uri is correct, and it works when using a hardlink path instead of a symlink

So the problem can either be nginx, docker, or maybe specifically the php-fpm configuration in nginx, I think

so far, I found some ideas on stackexchange sites, and I tried them without luck :

- adding explicitly `disable_symlinks off;` in nginx settings, in three context : http, server, location (both in `/` location and `~ \.php$` location)
- adding `autoindex on;` in nginx, in server and all locations context
- changing `$document_root` by `$realpath_root` in nginx like so :

  - `fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;`
- and adding those two lines :

  - `fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;`
  - `fastcgi_param   PATH_TRANSLATED $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;`
- giving read and execution permission to files and folders in both hardlink and symlink location
- changing owner of files and folders to the same as the hardlink that works (my nginx and wordpress docker are in two containers)

I don't know what else to do ?

##### requests :

the wordpress GET request that fails (code and request and headers) :

- `wp_enqueue_style('my_style', plugins_url('style.css', __FILE__));`
- `https://localhost/wp-content/plugins/my_plugin/style.css`
- headers :

```
GET https://localhost/wp-content/plugins/my_plugin/style.css?ver=6.0.3
Status 404 Not Found
Version HTTP/1.1
Transferred 294 B (146 B size)
Referrer Policy strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

the wordpress GET request that works (hardlink) (code and request and headers) :

- `wp_enqueue_style('my_style', plugins_url( 'test_plugin/style.css', dirname(__FILE__) ));`
- `https://localhost/wp-content/plugins/test_plugin/style.css`
- headers :

```
GET https://localhost/wp-content/plugins/test_plugin/style.css?ver=6.0.3
Status 200 OK
Version HTTP/1.1
Transferred 548 B (318 B size)
Referrer Policy strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

##### the architecture :

```
                                 /
drwxr-xr-x  www-data:www-data    | home/
drwxr-xr-x  www-data:www-data    | | www-data
drwxr-xr-x  www-data:www-data    | | | my_plugin/
-rwxr-xr-x  www-data:www-data    | | | | index.php
-rwxr-xr-x  www-data:www-data    | | | | style.css
drwxr-xr-x  root:root            | var/
drwxr-xr-x  root:root            | | www/
drwxr-xr-x  www-data:www-data    | | | html/
drwxr-xr-x  www-data:www-data    | | | | wp-content/
drwxr-xr-x  www-data:www-data    | | | | | plugins/
lrwxrwxrwx  www-data:www-data    | | | | | | my_plugin/ -> /home/www-data/my_plugin
drwxr-xr-x  www-data:www-data    | | | | | | test_plugin/
-rwxr-xr-x  www-data:www-data    | | | | | | | style.css
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, it was a really dumb error of mine :

I forgot to gives to Nginx-Container the volume which contains the hardlink ! so, in Nginx container, the hardlink pointed to by the symlink didn't existed indeed